# Setting animation speed at 2px per second?

Tags: jquery, animation

How does one set the animation speed so it moves at 2 pixels per second? Here the length of of my block is 310 px. I want it to move at 2 pixels per second.

```
$('#one').mouseenter(function(){
 $('.alt0').animate({width: "310px"}, 150000, function(){
    $('#refresh-1').show();
})
 $('#song-title1').show()
});
$('#refresh-1').click(function(){
$('.alt0').width(0);
$(this).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your animation duration to `310/2*1000` ( half second per pixel times 1000 milliseconds ) and your animation easing to "linear".

`$('.alt0').animate( {width: "310px"}, 310/2*1000, "linear" );`

[Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/kelvinss/zy9m3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for any width :

```
$('.bar1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.alt0').animate(
        {width: $(this).width()},
        ($(this).width())/2*1000,"linear",
        function(){
            $("#button").show();
        })
});
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#button").hide();
    $(".alt0").width(0);
                             });
```

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeMcP/5/)